# Python 3: maketime()

Tags: python

Rookie question:

the following works:

```
import time
# create time 
dztupel = 1971, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 
print(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", dztupel)) 
damals = time.mktime(dztupel)
# output 
lt = time.localtime(damals)
wtage = ["Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag", "Sonntag"]
wtagnr = lt[6]
print("Das ist ein", wtage[wtagnr])

tag_des_jahres = lt[7]
print("Der {0:d}. Tag des Jahres".format(tag_des_jahres))
```

but:

```
dztupel = 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

does not work,at least not at windows 10. edit: I get out of range error.
But time should start at January 1st 1970 at 0 hour 0 min and 0 seconds. shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Arman I have reformated the code

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: if you print dztupel=1971, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0  you get dztupel!

Comment: @deceze: U edit the question: I get an out of range error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second snippet, check out what the `time.mktime()` function returns, given that `dztupel` represents a datetime of 11:01am UTC on 1/1/1969 (shows as one hour ahead because of BST (i.e., UTC+0100) locally on my system):

```
>>> import time
>>> dztupel = 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0  # In BST locally for me, remember, so one hour less seconds than printed EPOCH seconds
>>> time.mktime(dztupel) # This command
-3599.0  # seconds after (i.e., before as is negative) 1/1/1970 UTC0000
```

It's negative because EPOCH time (which `time.mktike` is printing, in seconds) starts at UTC midnight on 1/1/1970:

```
>>> dztupel = 1970, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  # 1/1/1970 BST0100 == 1/1/1970 UTC0000
>>> time.mktime(dztupel)
0.0  # seconds after 1/1/1970 UTC0000
```

Hence `0.0`, as it's 0 seconds since `dztupel = 1970, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` since BST 0100 on 1/1/1970, or since UTC midnight on 1/1/1970.

---

Really, we want to print as UTC, so instead of `time.localtime()`, use `time.gmtime()`:

```
>>> dztupel = 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 
>>> time.gmtime(time.mktime(dztupel))
time.struct_time(tm_year=1969, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=23, tm_min=0, tm_sec=1, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=365, tm_isdst=0)
```

Then use `strftime()` to format it:

```
>>> gmt = time.gmtime(time.mktime(dztupel))
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmt)
'1969-12-31 23:00:01'
```